# android how to make relativelayout not clickable and its itme clickable

Tags: android, android-layout

i have a listview with relativelayout header, when i click on any space in the relativelayout it becomes white, i don't want that white, if the user click on the space, nothing will happend, but if he clicks on the image into that relativelayout  there is action i can handle it in onclick.

this is the relative layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rl_simple_list_item_header"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/orderMeal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:id="@+id/tv_restaurant_description_orderMeal"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/order_meal" />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/iv_simple_list_item_header_favorite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/favorite"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/favorite"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

## edit

```
01-25 21:00:42.718: E/AndroidRuntime(24121): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-25 21:00:42.718: E/AndroidRuntime(24121): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Syriatel.EatTel/com.Syriatel.EatTel.Restaurant_Description}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-25 21:00:42.718: E/AndroidRuntime(24121):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1659)
01-25 21:00:42.718: E/AndroidRuntime(24121):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
01-25 21:00:42.718: E/AndroidRuntime(24121):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
01-25 21:00:42.718: E/AndroidRuntime(24121):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
01-25 21:00:42.718: E/AndroidRuntime(24121):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-25 21:00:42.718: E/AndroidRuntime(24121):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-25 21:00:42.718: E/AndroidRuntime(24121):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
01-25 21:00:42.718: E/AndroidRuntime(24121):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-25 21:00:42.718: E/AndroidRuntime(24121):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-25 21:00:42.718: E/AndroidRuntime(24121):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
01-25 21:00:42.718: E/AndroidRuntime(24121):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
01-25 21:00:42.718: E/AndroidRuntime(24121):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-25 21:00:42.718: E/AndroidRuntime(24121): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-25 21:00:42.718: E/AndroidRuntime(24121):    at com.Syriatel.EatTel.Restaurant_Description.initialize(Restaurant_Description.java:46)
01-25 21:00:42.718: E/AndroidRuntime(24121):    at com.Syriatel.EatTel.Restaurant_Description.onCreate(Restaurant_Description.java:35)
01-25 21:00:42.718: E/AndroidRuntime(24121):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-25 21:00:42.718: E/AndroidRuntime(24121):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
01-25 21:00:42.718: E/AndroidRuntime(24121):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make your `RelativeLayout` focusable:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rl_simple_list_item_header"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >
```

**UPDATE**

If you want clickable `TextView` inside your header you can do it this way:

```
View header = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.simple_list_item_header, null);
View favorite = header.findViewById(R.id.iv_simple_list_item_header_favorite);

lv_restaurantInformation = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_restaurant_description_information);
lv_restaurantInformation.addHeaderView(header);

favorite.setOnClickListener(this);
```

And then handle it in `onClick` method of the `Activity`:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.iv_simple_list_item_header_favorite:
        Toast.makeText(this, "onClick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: do u know who can i get the elements from the listview header on activity ?

Comment: please check my edit, i added the code, would you tell me how to get the image view on my activity ?

Comment: I don't see any `ImageView` in the layout

Comment: never minde of it , now your code make the layout and its elements is clickable , i want the textviews to still clickable

Comment: `tv_favorite = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.iv_simple_list_item_header_favorite);
 

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  switch (v.getId()) {
  case R.id.iv_simple_list_item_header_favorite:
   tv_favorite.setText("TTTTTTTT");
   break;

  default:
   break;
  }
 }`

Comment: i get an exception , i update the question with that exception , sorry  i am making you angry :(

Comment: please check if you are using correct `R.layout.XXX` and `R.id.XXX` values. I guess I spell it wrong

Comment: i will start and new question when i know how to click the header item, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Set layout clickable, without any onClickListener

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/info1"
            android:clickable="true">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you assign the onclicklistener to the actual item rather then the implementing it in the activity this shouldn't be a problem.

```
tv_favorite = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.iv_simple_list_item_header_favorite);
tv_favorite.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        tv_favorite.setText("asdfasdfasdf");
}

});
```

If you want individual items in the ListView(not the header) you should use a OnItemClickListener that is set for the entire ListView.

Comment: there is no onitemclicklisterner because i use activity class not listactivity

Comment: no you can do `lv_restaurantInformation.setOnItemClickListener(...)' that will only get clicks for the items in the list, I think this what you are trying to actually do

Your question is a bit confusing, can you make a diagram and show which parts you actually want to be clickable?

Comment: i make this `  tv_favorite = (TextView) header
    .findViewById(R.id.iv_simple_list_item_header_favorite);


  lv_restaurantInformation.addHeaderView(header);

  lv_restaurantInformation.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
     long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(arg3 == R.id.iv_simple_list_item_header_favorite)
     tv_favorite.setText("asdfasdfasdf");
   }
  });
` but nothing happend, is that the header is unclickable ?

Comment: i don't know what is the good andwer, i will try myself , thanks alot